# How to update column data based on the select and update query

Tags: mysql, sql-update

i have following data

```
| 2015-08-30 01:23:01 |
| 2015-08-30 03:14:50 |
| 2015-08-30 04:29:55 |
| 2015-08-30 09:18:57 |
| 2015-08-30 13:36:51 |
| 2015-08-31 02:19:33 |
| 2015-08-31 03:14:59 |
| 2015-08-31 04:33:10 |
| 2015-08-31 10:56:42 |
| 2015-08-31 12:25:54 |
| 2015-09-01 02:29:00 |
| 2015-09-01 03:19:40 |
| 2015-09-01 04:47:51 |
| 2015-09-01 13:56:06 |
| 2015-09-02 03:15:13 |
| 2015-09-02 03:35:53 |
| 2015-09-02 04:16:31 |
| 2015-09-03 03:12:03 |
| 2015-09-03 03:37:21 |
| 2015-09-03 05:01:30 |
```

above data is a `datetime` column in a table `build`

now i need to write the query to accomplish following

1: change the year from 2015 to 2019 and rest everything should remain as it is

so this is how i have written the query

```
mysql> UPDATE buildinfo SET datetime = '2019%' where datetime = (select a.datetime from buildinfo as a where datetime LIKE '2015%');
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'buildinfo' for update in FROM clause
mysql>
```

i am not sure how to write this. i have seen lot of docs and some of them mentioned about the INNER JOIN but cant get that.

please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This**

```
UPDATE buildinfo set datetime = replace(datetime, '2015', '2019') where datetime LIKE '2015%';
```

It will change 2015 to 2019 in datetime column and rest everything should remain.

- But before applying this make a backup of stored data.

Comment: maybe it's best to avoid string functions on `DATETIME` datatypes.. As shown by @danblack `LIKE` stopt working on `DATETIME` datatype in MySQL 8, maybe a matter of a few updates before string functions like `REPLACE()` also stop working.. who knows?

Comment: I'm getting the WHERE clause [failing on 5.7](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=906c2f833b795ac646edb51863cf1213) so 5.6 and MariaDB are working options only. Might be workable in some SQL mode set but that's just working with hacks.

Answer (score 1):

datetime values aren't always a string and you might find in MySQL-8.0 they don't work. Luckily there is a rich amount of [date and time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

So:

```
UPDATE buildinfo
SET datetime=DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL 4 YEAR)
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Well, you *can*. Also, note that `WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 23:59:59'` takes longer to type, but is faster to execute (on an indexed table)

Comment: You definitely *can* use string matching functions

Comment: You used to be able to use string functions, [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cdab940887a0329d274652dd67598e97), seemed to stop in MySQL8.0.X though <=5.7 and MariaDB still can do it.

Comment: which makes sense as DATETIME is not a VARCHAR CHAR or TEXT datatype where a `LIKE` should work on.  i wonder if `REPLACE()` the accepted answer will still work in MySQL 8

Comment: *"which makes sense as DATETIME is not a VARCHAR CHAR or TEXT datatype where a LIKE should work on. i wonder if REPLACE() the accepted answer will still work in MySQL 8"*  Got to love the inconsistency in MySQL.. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d0350d4ef12948d0528ff2c4886b79f7

Comment: REPLACE actually does work. Yeh, consistency, and compatibility, gotta love it.

Comment: maybe a matter of a few updates before string functions like `REPLACE()` also stop working on that `DATETIME` datatype who knows?

Answer (score 1):

Add 4 years to the dates where the year is 2015:

```
UPDATE buildinfo 
SET datetime = DATE_ADD(datetime, INTERVAL 4 YEAR)
WHERE YEAR(datetime) = 2015;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8Va5MPKpAmryTPCTZguP1P/0).

Answer (score 0):

Please try Using DATE_FORMAT with Update Query

```
UPDATE buildinfo
SET `datetime` = DATE_FORMAT(`datetime`,'2019-%m-%d %T')
WHERE YEAR(`datetime`) = '2015';
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to danblacks answer, using string matching functions:

```
UPDATE
  build
SET
  `datetime` = CONCAT('2019', RIGHT(`datetime`, 15))
WHERE
  LEFT(`datetime`, 4) = '2015'
```

danblacks is doing it the correct way, though. I would recommend using his answer.

Comment: Having trouble getting this to [work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=58d4f698afa2072861d066fced42021e), pick any version.

Comment: You're right, I should have cast the `datetime` first, instead I will remove the `like` function and use `left`

Comment: maybe it's best to avoid string functions on `DATETIME` datatypes.. As shown by @danblack `LIKE` stopt working on `DATETIME` datatype in MySQL 8, maybe a matter of a few updates before string functions like `RIGHT()` and 'LEFT()' also stop working.. who knows?

Comment: Perhaps... I'd agree it is definitely not the best way of doing it - however, I'm not a fan of the idea *"the developers* **might** *deprecate a feature, so we should stop using it."* Once deprecation is confirmed, sure. But until then its completely valid, perhaps just bad practice?

Comment: Also `+` is SQL Server concat in MySQL you need to use `CONCAT()` i just noticed..  *"however, I'm not a fan of the idea "the developers might deprecate a feature, so we should stop using it."* Well it has been defined in the ANSI/ISO SQL standards how string functions should work and on which datatypes so It's not really deprecation it is misusage from the start.. Same example where MySQL allowed non aggregate columns in the select which are not in the GROUP BY in the past it is not valid with the ANSI/ISO SQL standards in mind but at the costs you played russian roulette with your resultset.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  +1. I hadn't checked the SQL standards on string functions, but having now done so I am inclined to agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

If the update

```
UPDATE
   buildinfo
SET datetime = '2019%'
where datetime = (
  select
     a.datetime
  from  
    buildinfo as a
  where datetime LIKE '2015%'
);
```

is correct as i didn't check it. 
You can rewrite it a bit so MySQL does accept it without giving a error.

```
UPDATE
   buildinfo
SET datetime = '2019%'
where datetime = (
  select alias.datetime from(
    select
       a.datetime
    from  
      buildinfo as a
    where datetime LIKE '2015%'
  ) alias
);
```

**But** when looking into your example table/data, the following query is better.

```
UPDATE
  buildinfo
SET
 buildinfo.datetime = buildinfo.datetime + INTERVAL 4 YEAR
WHERE
 YEAR(buildinfo.datetime) = 2015
```